# bash : syntax to compute modulus

Tags: bash, if-statement, modulus

What is correct bash syntax for modulus ?

My script has a loop that needs to take some action each 100 repetitions ( such as write to a log ) :

```
counter = 0
...
divisor = 100
remainder = 0
remainder = counter%=divisor
if $remainder = 0; then ...; else ... ; fi
```

but I receive error :

```
counter%=divisor: command not found
```

Comment: You seem to be having more basic problems. You can't have spaces around `=` in variable assignments.

Comment: Your script does not look at all like Bash -- or if it is, it's very bizarre Bash. `counter = 0`, for example, calls the program `counter` with the arguments `=` and `0`.

Comment: does bash include the concept of declaring and initializing a variable ?

Comment: obLink to http://shellcheck.net/ here.  Check your script for basic syntax errors before posting, please.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few different ways to get arithmetic context in bash. I usually use double parens

```
(( remainder = counter % divisor ))
```

Comment: `if (( counter % divisor )) -eq 0; then ...` yields " syntax error near unexpected token '-eq' "

Comment: The proper syntax for that is `if (( counter % divisor == 0 )); then`